# Override getValue and setValue to capselate a Pair

Tags: kotlin

Let's say I have following class:

```
class Person() {
    var age: Pair<String, Int> = Pair("person_age", 23)
    // override getValue and setValue here
}
```

Now I want to capsulate the actual `Pair` and only want the user to read/write the second value of the pair. Is it possible to override the `getValue` and `setValue` methods so I can do something like this:

```
val p = Person()
p.age = 25

if(p.age <= 30)
```

Of course I can write own `getter` and `setter` methods for each property but one nice thing about Kotlin is that you have to write such less boilerplate code which will get lost then.

Comment: Why don't you use `var age : Int` instead and return `"person_age" to age` when needed?

Answer (score 1):

The following should probably already suffice:

```
class Person() {
  var age : Int = 23 // public by default
  private /* or internal */ fun toAgePair() = "person_age" to age // narrow visibility
}
```

So all your code accesses the age as you have shown:

```
val p = Person()
p.age = 25
if (p.age <= 30) ...
```

But if you require your `Pair` you just do the following instead:

```
p.toAgePair() // or skip that method and use: '"person_age" to p.age' instead
```

Alternatives to access the `Pair` content are: `Pair.first`, `Pair.second` or [destructured](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html), e.g.:

```
val myPair = Pair("person_age", 23)
// myPair.second = 25 // setting will not work however
myPair.let { (name, age) -> /* do something with it */ }
```

Or alternatively:

```
val p = Person()
val (name, age) = p.toAgePair()
// age = 25 // setting will not work however (and it wouldn't set the actual value inside the Pair if it would contain vars)
if (age < 30) // accessing is OK
```

However then you get access to both values which you probably didn't want in the first place, if I understood you correctly.
You could overcome the setting part using your own `data class` with a `var` but then again, you do not really gain something from it.

Answer (score 1):

> Now I want to capselate the actual Pair and only want the user to read/write the second value of the pair.

Assuming this means you want the first value to be final, but not the second one, there are some options.

If you only want one of the values to be writeable and readable, don't use a pair. It's not designed to be used like that. All the items of a Pair are `val`s.

If you want a Pair either way, can do this:

```
class Person(var age: Int = 23){
    val pair: Pair<String, Int>
        get() = Pair("person_age", age)
    //Alternatively, if you don't want to use a property:
    //fun getPair() = "person_age" to age
}
```

What this does is creating a final pair where the first value can't be modified, but the second can.

So now:

```
fun example(){
    val person = Person()
    person.age = 25;//Fine: Age is an int, and a var
    //person.pair = Pair("something", 45)//fails: "Val cannot be reassigned
    val pair = person.pair // Allowed. Accessing the pair still works
    assert(pair.second == person.age) // This is true
}
```

However, if you're fine with a non-Pair solution, this works too:

```
data class Person (var age: Int, val string: String = "person_age")

fun example(){
    val person = Person(23)
    val (name, string) = person// Allowed! Just like with Pairs
    person.age = 25; // Also allowed
    //person.string = "something"//Not allowed
}
```

The n-touple unpacking is supported for data classes. If you don't have a data class, you need to declare an `operator fun` for each component you want to unpack. Example:

```
class Person (val string: String = "person_age", var age: Int){
    operator fun component1() = string
    operator fun component2() = age
}
```

But tbh, it sounds like the `data class` solution is the one you're looking for. It would lock the String to what it's initialized with, and because of the default value and its position, you can initialize it with a single positioned argument*

You could also use generics if you want to use the same class for multiple types.

<sub>* Assumes the code is in Kotlin. Positioned and default arguments don't work from Java code.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend you to use `Pair` at all. Maybe you could modify it (inherit from it, use extension functions) to suit your needs, but why try to change something as simple as Pair?. It is much easier and in this case also cleaner to just create your own class which suits your needs:

```
data class MyPair<out A, B>(
    val first: A, 
    var second: B
)

val pair = MyPair("age", 1)
pair.second = 2
pair.first = 1 // error
```

This class has all important features which `Pair` has: generic types for `first` and `second`, and you can use destructuring declarations.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to overwrite a getter method in Kotlin

```
class Person {
    var age: Int = 0
       get() = if (field < 0) 0 else field 

}
```

The attribute is accessed directly

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val p = Person()
    p.age = -28
    println(p.age) //0
}
```